# ASP.NET does not contain definition for junction table?

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an issue when trying to access my junction table. I get the error that `'db'` does not contain the definition for `'junction'` table.

My entity for the table looks like this:

```
    [Key]
    [Required()]
    public int PersonID{get;set;}

    [Key]
    [Required()]
    public string WorkName {get;set;}
```

I think the error may be in the DbContext:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<DirectorsMovieJunction>()
            .HasKey(o => new {o.PersonID, o.WorkName});
```

The relation of the tables is many to many.

I am using .NET v6.0.1

Comment: ASP.NET Core is a web app platform, not a data access library. It has *nothing* to do with databases. It looks like you have an EF Core question. Which EF Core version are you using? EF Core 5? EF Core 6? What are the *entities* you use? And why such a weird *entity* name, `DirectorsMovieJunction` ? If your code had `Director` and `Movie` classes, the tables generated by EF Core would be `Directors`, `Movies` and `DirectorMovies`. Have you actually created a table named `DirectorsMovieJunctions` in the database?

Comment: Yes, I have that table present in the database. EF core is 6.0.1

Comment: Post your DbContext.